# Sumar atributos de un objeto Android

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, listview, android-recyclerview

Buenas estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, tengo un objeto que es una lista con un nombre y un precio:

```
class superMarkerProvider {
companion object {
    val markerList = listOf<SuperMarkerModel>(
        SuperMarkerModel("Arroz",80.73),
        SuperMarkerModel("Mayonesa",120.82),
        SuperMarkerModel("Queso",326.36),
        SuperMarkerModel("Leche",85.45),
        SuperMarkerModel("Cerveza",96.03),
        SuperMarkerModel("Galletitas",20.00),

    )
}
```

}

Hasta acá todo genial, funciona bien el *reciclerView*, el problema es que quiero sumar todos los elementos numéricos para devolver un total de compra, si bien puedo obtener el numero de la lista, no puedo sumarlos, muestro el código:

```
    objetoSUperMercado.markerList.forEach { it:SuperMarkerModel
       // println("Valor = $it")
        //val num = it.price
        //val num2 = it.price
        //println("Total: $total")

        var total = 0.0
        total = total + it.price
        println(total)
    }
```

este es el model de *supermarker*

```
data class SuperMarkerModel(val nameProduct:String, val price:Double )
```

¿Alguna solución de como puedo sumar todos los `price` y guardarlos en una variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//debe declararce fuera del for 

//si lo haces adentro como lo tenias cada iteracion lo reiniciabas
var finalPrice:Double = 0.00   
 
objetoSUperMercado.markerList.forEach { it:SuperMarkerModel
finalPrice=   finalPrice+it.price   
//valor sumando por iteracion
 println(finalPrice)  
}

//debes imprimirlo fuera de el forEach
//valor final
 println(finalPrice)
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciono muchas gracias!